# React native project initialization, ios library linking

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

When initializing a new project I see there are 2 options :

- react-native init AwesomeProject
- create-react-native-app AwesomeProject (I chose this)

I have been trying to install react-native-navigation v2.0. There are instructions to modify the libraries within xcode. I'm unable to open my project in xcode. My new AwesomeProject does not have an .xcodeproj item. I'm having trouble understanding :

- do all RN projects have a .xcodeproj item
- are there fundamentals differences between the above project initialization commands where I actually won't be able to modify library files via xcode?

Thanks

Comment: I see now that on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html under 'see caveats' this is clearly explained... I will eject the project

Answer (score 0):

The .xcodeproj is inside the `/ios` dir.

I haven't used `create-react-native-app` in quite some time, but I don't see why it wouldn't have an `/ios` folder.